# How to access the Entity Framework data model from code behind in a web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have generated an ADO.NET data model from my database in Visual Studio 2015, the generated class in `myEntities.Context.cs` is named `myEntities` and inherits from `DbContext`.

I want to extract objects data via LINQ from the model in code behind in `MyPage.cs`.

From my book and tutorials, I can see that to make this, you make an instance of the model class, in my case `myEntities` and run the LINQ query over it.

However, when I try to instance this class it is not found. The class is `public` in the namespace `MyAppName.App_Code` and `MyPage.cs` is in the namespace `MyAppName`.

I can't seem to include the `MyAppName.App_Code` namespace in my code behind for `MyPage.cs`, Visual Studio tells me that it's redundant and the code behind still doesn't see or accept the class `myEntities`.

**Edit:**
More clear:
In MyEntities.Context.cs in App_Code folder

```
namespace MyApp.App_Code
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }
}}
```

Code behind of MyPage.cs

```
namespace MyApp
{
 public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public IQueryable ListView_GetData()
    {
        //can't use the MyEntities class here, tried to add the
        //MyApp.App_code namespace above, still did't work
        var data = MyEntities();

        //my LINQ operations

        return null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code please? Are you using the database first or code first approach?

Comment: Database first, thanks

Comment: You should read the section on `App_Code` here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx. I would suggest moving this code outside the `App_Code` folder into a folder named `Data` or similar then try referencing again.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Different namespaces were the issue.

Comment: Great :) have added answer with a bit more detail for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx):

> Code in the App_Code folder is referenced automatically in your
>   application.

Putting your `DbContext` class in `App_Code` means it will be automatically available anywhere in your application without an explicit reference. So you would be able to write:

```
var exampleTableEntities = MyEntities.ExampleTableEntities;
```

If you want an explicit reference, I would suggest moving your `DbContext` outside the `App_Code` folder into a folder named `Data`, `Domain` or something similar. Then reference from your code file.